# How to use a Custom label expression in a flexipagecomponent?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a default lightning Home Page.
In the Home_page_Default.flexipage-meta.xml you can clearly see the structure of the page:

- FlexiPage

  - FlexiPageRegion

    - ComponentInstances

      - ComponentInstanceProperties

(as shown in [Flexipage documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flexipage.htm) )

In one such FlexiPageRegion, I want to use a custom label so that my users can see the LC label in their own translated language.

```
 <componentInstanceProperties>
     <name>label</name>
     <value>{!$Label.c.Title_HomePage}</value>
 </componentInstanceProperties>
```

I am unable to do so as on saving this code, I am getting the error that:

> The 'label' attribute does not support expressions.

Is there workaround for this?